# Best back end file upload parallelism technique

Tags: django, file-upload

In my web application (Django), I am sending multiple files to the backend. I need to implement a parallel file upload technique which will make use of maximum CPU core capacity. I am ready to implement it it any language or any tool.

Please someone suggest best tools or techniques to implement this, so that file saving to backend server (to hard disk or database) should be completed in much less time compared to normal file upload.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is about making upload parallel in the back-end, and you might think of doing something on front-end, where you take your files split into chunks and send chunks to back-end by ajax. HTML5 allows you to split the file on front-end and send chunk-by-chunk to server. So you can try using some of JS plugins which will help to achieve this